# How to make the consumer know that the Producer has finished sending all the messages to the Broker?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

1: We are working on a near real time processing or Batch Processing using Spark Streaming. Our current design has Kafka included.

2: Every 15 minutes the Producer will send the messages.

3: We plan to use Spark Streaming to consume messages from Kafka topic.

Answer (score 2):

That a very broad question:

1. Basically, there is no such thing as "all messages" because it's stream processing (but I still understand your question).
2. One way would be to inject a control message at last message that "ends a burst of data"
3. You could also use some "side communication channel" via an RPC such that the producer send the last offset it did write to the consumer
4. You could put an heuristic -- if `poll()` does return nothing for 1 minute, you just assume that all data got consumed

And there might be other methods... But it's all hand coded -- there is no support in Kafka (cf. (1.)).